# Django Contact Form with Bootstrap

Tags: django, forms, email, bootstrap-4

I have app called contact that renders extends of home.html with footer/header. I put bootstrap form in there with below code:

```
<div class="form-area">  
        <form role="form">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" maxlength="70" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" maxlength="70" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" type="textarea" id="message" placeholder="Message" maxlength="300" rows="7"></textarea>                
                    </div>

        <button type="button" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-m btn-secondary">Submit Form</button>
        </form>
```

I want to send emails using that form, I already know that I should use cripsy forms but I have no idea where to start. I am not sure if I should create model or form in django. There are some tutorials that show email logic and templates but they are using built-in forms.

Many thanks.

Comment: I wonder if it wouldn't be better to use Django  forms and then try to make them visually appealing afterwards.

Comment: please post your views which renders home and if want the information to be stored you can use models and attach forms to that which makes things easier

Comment: I replied to your comment with github repository

Answer (score 2):

**HTML file baar.html**

```
<div class="form-area">  
        <form role="form" method="post">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" maxlength="70" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" maxlength="70" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" type="textarea" id="message" placeholder="Message" maxlength="300" rows="7"></textarea>                
                    </div>

        <button type="button" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-m btn-secondary">Submit Form</button>
        </form>
```

**View.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.conf import settings
def fooview(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        name=request.POST.get('name')
        email=request.POST.get('email')
        subject=request.POST.get('subject')
        message=request.POST.get('message')
        send_mail(subject= subject,message= message,from_email=settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,recipient_list = [email],fail_silently  = True,)
        return redirect('fooview')
    return render(request,'baar.html',{})
```

**settings.py**

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL='someemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'username'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

Comment: Hi Pavan. Thank you for your response. I used your code but it didn't work.  https://github.com/adamwojt/portfolio

Comment: Change just remove action attr from your form. And what part of the code is not working

Comment: There is no need to import email configuration in settings just add them remove import

Comment: I did everything as above. When I go to the form and click submit nothing happens. No emails are being sent.

Comment: In the above code change fail_silently=False in views so the absolute error will be displayed

Answer (score 1):

First add email configuration to settings.py:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'EMAIL_PASSWORD'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'webmaster@localhost'
```

Next we will setup some URLS that can be directed to our views.  Update urls.py (import views from wherever they are located):

```
from . import views
url(r'^contact/$', views.contact, name='contact'),
url(r'^thanks/$', views.thanks, name='thanks'),

#For development
#EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

Now we need to set up the form.py itself:

```
from django import forms
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    contact_name = forms.CharField(required=True, label="Name")
    contact_email = forms.EmailField(required=True, label="Email")
    content = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.Textarea,
        label="Message"
    )
```

Here is the full views.py file with an explanation below:

```
from django.core.mail import BadHeaderError, EmailMessage
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import ContactForm

def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            contact_name = form.cleaned_data['contact_name']
            contact_email = form.cleaned_data['contact_email']
            content = form.cleaned_data['content']
            try:
                email = EmailMessage(contact_name,
                                    content,
                                    contact_email,
                                    ['youremail@gmail.com'], #change to your email
                                     reply_to=[contact_email],
                                   )
                email.send()
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('./thanks/')
    return render(request, 'home/contact.html', {'form': form})


def thanks(request):
    return render(request, 'home/thanks.html', {)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, got it working. Turns out there was something wrong with the bootstrap form. Also sorted out Django in this way:

views.py:

```
def contact(request):
    #check for POST requests on load.
    request.method == 'POST'
    subject = request.POST.get('subject')
    message = request.POST.get('message')
    email = request.POST.get('email')

    if subject and message and email:
        try:
            send_mail(subject, message, email, ['adam1edinburgh@gmail.com'])
        except BadHeaderError:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.') 
        return HttpResponse('Thanks for your email')

    else:
        #loading contacts.html if no requests
        return render(request, 'personal/contact.html')
```

It's bit weird but I first check if there is any POST requests and of course there is none because HTML is rendered if there is no requests.

Form code, button type was wrong. So I changed. Also csrf token turns out to be obligatory.

```
<div class="form-area">  
        <form role="form" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" maxlength="70" required>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" type="textarea" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message" maxlength="300" rows="7"></textarea>                
                    </div>

        <button type="submit"  name="submit" class="btn btn-m btn-secondary">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

Thank you all for help!!!

Comment: have a look at pip install django-widget-tweaks.